# suppress warnings to console emulator

Tags: react-native

specs:

1. console emulator Cmder
2. Windows 10 (64bit)
3. create-react-native-app
4. react native 54.2

Is it possible to suppress warning messages to the console emulator?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#warnings), you can use `console.disableYellowBox = true;`, during development.

Or you can ignore specific warning messages as

```
import {YellowBox} from 'react-native';
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning: ...']);
```

**Example**

```
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning: ReactNative.createElement']);
```